# How can we like a url using FB Login?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-like

I want to like a url using a like button as shown in the given link.

[At bottom Like button is there](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/)
click on the like button will like this page and shows in your facebook profile page under Activity block as shown below:

[image]

How can we like a url like that in iPhone App.If user is login with fb then just like if not login then login and then like.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for this : [Facebook like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have done it.

Code to like Page URL using graph API is as Follows:

```
    - (IBAction)likepageonFB:(id)sender
{
    [appDelegate openSession];

     NSString *likePage=@"http://www.facebook.com/ipreencekmr";

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   likePage, @"object",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"],@"access_token",
                                   nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"liked with id %@",[result valueForKey:@"id"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
    }];
}
```

You can check this example I have uploaded [FBLike Button](https://github.com/ipreencekmr/REPOSITORY)